# How to keep the cmd open?

Tags: java, console-application, executable-jar

When we click on .jar files which do not contain any GUI the CMD Prompt runs the code and exits it immediately.

How to make it remain open when running a .jar by double clicking on it?

Is there any java code for it? Just like the pause command in batch files or any? I prefer only by java code but not an OS way? and also not by running command java - jar *.jar in cmd prompt.

Comment: If writing a batch or some shell script to pause after executing is an option...

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually just open a command line first, as suggested in the other answer.

If you need a pure Java code solution though, just read from system in at the end of your code.  The window will stay open while waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Run the jar file from the command prompt

```
java -jar yourjarfilename.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines read a character from std-in along with a print statement telling people to "press any key" should do the trick, provided you have access to the java code that is.

if not well, best option is to drop to CMD and run the command manually.